# How to change font size in DarkScape?

Tags: darkscape

I started playing Darkscape - a new Jagex game based off Runescape, and I've run into a problem - all fonts seem too small for me!

Is there any way to increase font size in DarkScape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to change font size in DarkScape. [The recommendation from other players is to change the color to make it more readable on the background](https://www.reddit.com/r/runescape/comments/1v7k5q/as_someone_who_plays_on_various_monitors_i_would/).